# Why does not request?

Tags: python, django

please help fix the code.

model.py:

```
class Friends(models.Model):        
    user_id = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )   
    friend_id = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False, 
    )   

    @classmethod
    def get_entry(self, user_id, friend_id):
        return False
```

views.py:

```
@ login_required 
def user_personal(request, id):         
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        path_pk = id
        user_id = int(request.user.pk)

        if request.POST.get('action', '') == 'add':         
            try: 
                with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "add1.txt"), "wb") as f:
                    f.write(bytes(user_id, 'UTF-8'))                    
                Friends.get_entry(user_id=user_id, friend_id=path_pk)   #
            except: 
                with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "add2.txt"), "wb") as f:
                    f.write(bytes(user_id, 'UTF-8'))                                        
                Friends.set_entry(user_id=user_id, friend_id=path_pk)

    t = loader.get_template('user_personal.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {}) 
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

the problem is that when it works

```
user_personal (request, 3)
```

, Then there is a write debug file add1.txt. and there is no record debug file add2.txt. the content of the debug file add1.txt following:

```
NUL NUL
```

because this function does not work

```
Friends.get_entry (user_id = user_id, friend_id = path_pk)
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3, the [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) type represents a sequence of integers. Passing an integer to convert to a byte object will create a `bytes` type with a sequence of `NUL` characters, aka `\x00`, with the length of the integer passed. I guess that the `pk` of your user object is `2`, so the following line:

```
f.write(bytes(user_id, 'UTF-8'))
```

will write the integer sequence `\x00\x00` to the file. Your text editor represents this as `NUL NUL`.